# Como se puede acceder a una carpeta de red desde un script de VBScript

Tags: vbscript, vbs

En este momento tengo la necesidad de crear un script que copie los archivos de una carpeta compartida a una carpeta local pero tengo un error en la ruta de la ubicación de red.

El código que estoy empleando es este:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.CopyFolder "\\servidor\carpeta_compartida" , "C:\carpeta_local" , True
```

Tambien intente:

```
objFSO.CopyFolder "//servidor/carpeta_compartida" , "C:/carpeta_local" , True
```

Desde una carpeta local funciona correctamente con los slash de la primera forma.
He investigado y no he conseguido informacion con respecto a esto, agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```
CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFolder _
"\\E\\servidor\carpeta_compartida", _
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%") &
_
"\Escritorio\MiCarpetaLocal", True
```

Éxitos!

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, lo intente y no me funciono

Comment: Cambiaste las variables?